# Prop `aria-activedescendant` did not match. react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-select

i recently use react-select and its giving me an error which is :

`Prop`aria-activedescendant`did not match`

i just copy and paste the example in the github pages its working well except this error warning.

this is my code

```
<Select
   name={this.props.name}
   value={this.state.selectedOption}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   options={[
     { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
     { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
   ]}
 />
```

Comment: Have same error. Have you found a solution?

Comment: did you use serverside rendering ? i didnt found any solution for this haha

Comment: Yes, I'm using server-side rendering.

Answer (score 2):

After a look at the source code, I found out if you don't pass the prop `instanceId` react-select generates a new one. So, in order to get rid of the warning pass the prop.

```
<Select
   name={this.props.name}
   instanceId={this.props.name}
   value={this.state.selectedOption}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   options={[
     { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
     { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
   ]}
 />
```